# What do you mean by a matchday in football?

Tags: football, match-identification

Does matchday in football (soccer) mean the day a match was scheduled or the day it was played? Also how can a matchday occur on two different days? For ex- matchday 25 below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Matchday is not just a single day (although it *can* happen that all games are played on a single day). It is usually a weekend where all teams play once.

A championship (or at least the major ones) has every club playing each other club twice, which ends in a total of 34 games in the Bundesliga (I'm using the BL to answer because your screenshot is about that one).

This also means there are 9 games per round/weekend (18 clubs playing = 9 games). **This set of 9 games is a matchday** and 34 matchdays are a season.

For example this one from this weekend is from Friday to Sunday:

[image]